# CSS triangle issue in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, css

I need to use CSS triangle to create and arrow. This is the one Im working on: http://jsfiddle.net/7vRca/

```
<div class="arrow-outer"></div>

.arrow-outer{
border: 1em solid transparent;
border-top-color: #3bb0d7;
border-right-color: #3bb0d7;
height: 0;
width: 0;
```

}

[image]

The issue is that in chrome it looks perfect. But in firefox there is a small bent in the middle.

Any idea why this is happening and how can I make it look smooth as in chrome?

Comment: Looks the same to me in both browsers on win7- FF17.01 and Chrome 23.0.1271.97

Comment: Im seeing a small 1px rough/broken edge in the middle, whre two border meet. Im using mac osx.

Comment: I do _not_ see it in jsfiddle, FF17.0.1, Win8 ...straight and smooth.

Comment: Then how come Im seeing it?! Any idea? I have posted the screenshot.

Comment: @goose What happens when you press `Ctrl + 0` (resetting zoom)? Sometimes the aliasing gets messed up when you are zoomed in/out.

Comment: @goose I just opened the jsfiddle in Firefox as well as in Chrome, I can not reproduce it neither. What version of FF are you running on? And happens in Safari and Opera? Edit: I can reproduce it when I set the height to 1px. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake here somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't got a mac to test unfortunately and Firefox on Windows seems to render correctly. You could get around the problem though...

```
.arrow-outer {
  border: 2em solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-color: #3bb0d7;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

Instead of rendering the triangle as two sides of the border, it flattens the right border to achieve the same shape using only the top border, circumventing any alignment issues (illustrated below).

[image: Border right-angled triangle]

It is possible that Firefox on Mac OS is rendering the div as a pixel height which might be solved using an overflow hidden, but it is equally if not more likely that the rounding in the rendering algorithm has resulted in different pixels being selected for the edge of the right border for that combination of browser and OS. That would be my guess as to why it is happening.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. :) Could you help me understand whats happening here?

Comment: I've added a bit about my guess as to why it might be happening. I'm assuming you understand how my workaround works though. Let me know if you don't

Answer (score 1):

Setting 'inset' for the transparent borders helped for me. I found this trick here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/#comment-103785

Answer (score 1):

Try add this into css:

```
 -moz-transform: scale(.9999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RGB instead of transparent,

```
<div class="arrow-outer"></div>

.arrow-outer{
   border: 1em solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
   border-top-color: #3bb0d7;
   border-right-color: #3bb0d7;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
}
```

as we did here: [Weird dark border :after css arrow in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956228/weird-dark-border-after-css-arrow-in-firefox)

---

EDIT: by the way, it worsk in both ways in my Firefox (one with the gray line, the others without, but never the effect you described...)

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it :/