# Small line showing up on ::before element when scaled on hover

Tags: html, css

Im having a problem with a `:before` element (a left pointing triangle) getting a small line through the middle of it when I `transform: scale` on `:hover` I'm not sure what is causing this.. I have seen the same effect on other websites and it doesn't happen.

Any help would be appreciated

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 45vw;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.image{
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%
}

.text{
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%
}

.text:before{
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  top: 50%;
  left: -17px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid yellow;
}

.text:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

view on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wap184pe/1/

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more where exactly the erroneous line is? I don't see it.

Comment: I will post screenshot

Comment: Also, what browser?

Comment: updated question, running firefox developer edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This workaround essentially makes a triangle twice the size of the triangle you have and hides half of it, so the thin border is not visible. Check out [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054145/css-triangle-issue-in-firefox) with rendering triangles as borders in Firefox.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 45vw;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.image{
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%
}

.text{
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%
}

.text:before{
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  top: 35%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 36px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.text:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the arrow at generator at http://www.cssarrowplease.com, you can save yourself the trouble

Comment: Thanks this is also a great solution!