# Shadow & Distortion Between Border Sides In Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, border

I've been using CSS border properties along with the pseudo elements :before and :after to give my elements the appearance of geometric shapes, a simple example would be like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="shapeOne"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#shapeOne
{
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   margin:20px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:200px 200px 200px 200px;
   border-color:transparent #f00 #0f0 transparent;  
}
```

So by making two of the borders transparent, and giving two colour I've effectively made a triangular shape.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VTzS9/1/

This seems to display fine in all browsers except Firefox (and specifically the PC version, as it looks normal on Firefox on Macs). The issue is that Firefox seems to place a shadow/distortion effect between the border sides and create a 'kink' in the border (where the empty element would be) - and this effect increases as the difference in sizes between the different border sides increases - so with with equal border sizes (my first shape in the link above) the issue is barely (but still) noticeable, however as the difference between border sizes increases (shape two and three in my link) the effect becomes more pronounced.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this, and if there is anything I can do to remove the effect?

Cheers!

Comment: and +1 for the beautyful test-case on jsFiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
rgba(255,255,255,0)
```

instead of

```
transparent
```

.

This will make it works on Firefox too.

> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SkXXy/

P.S: same problem of here: [Weird dark border :after css arrow in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956228/weird-dark-border-after-css-arrow-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks Andrea - I'd search a few times and not found that other question.

Comment: Yeah, the title was hard to find, maybe your will be more easy to find for future askers... please accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: That solution only *kinda* fixes the problem - essentially it allows you to control the color of the shadow/distorted section of the border - so you can match it to the background behind your element, however you still get the shadow/distortion effect as well as the kink in the middle

Comment: I think this is related to how Firefox handles the borders of pseudo elements. I opened your fiddle in Chrome and it is "stepped", it creates an ugly "stair" effect. Firefox instead "blurs" the borders, creating a smooth and polished effect... i personally prefer the way Firefox does (except for the fact that you can't use `transparent`, that is a bug), but i don't think you can do nothing else about that...

Comment: Yes, the Chrome stepped effect isn't great - for once it seems to be IE that's coming out on top with a nice smooth line and no wierdness :D

Comment: Uh ?! Do you mean IE9 ? I just opened the fiddle with IE8, it's identical to Chrome version :)

Comment: Yep IE9 is looking strong! IE8 does have the same stepped sadness :(

Comment: Firefox on PC still shows a steps effect for shape2 and shape3. Not sure if there exists another alternative to making it look sleek.