# Pseudo element :after not working in IE9 with content:"Γû╝"

Tags: css

Hi all I added `content: "▼"` in a CSS3 `:after` pseudo element and it's not working clearly in IE9.

It shows `"Γû╝"` like this symbol. I added `<meta>` tag correctly.

my css

```
#get-in {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
  width: 74px;
  line-height: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 15px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
}
#get-in:after {
  content: "▼";
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

is there any problem with my code or IE9 won't support..? is there any fix ?

Comment: Try adding an `@charset` rule at the *top* of your stylesheet - e.g. `@charset "utf-8"` - just make sure nothing precedes this.

Comment: @l2aelba - actually, you'd need a unicode escape sequence in CSS `content`, not url-encoding.

Comment: @Adrift  yes now it works problem am working with SASS so i forgot to put '@charset "utf-8"' thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The character encoding of the CSS file has not been declared properly. Primarily, make sure that it is actually UTF-8 encoded *and* declared as UTF-8 encoded in HTTP headers. You can additionally put `@charset "utf-8"` at the start of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#get-in:after {
  content:'\25BC';
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

SRC : http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html
*(Paste ▼ symbol into **Paste a character here**)*

Answer (score 0):

**The immediate problem**

From [Declaring character encodings in CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php):

> It is a good idea to always declare the encoding of external CSS style sheets if you have any non-ASCII text in your CSS file.

```
@charset "<IANA-defined-charset-name>";
```

then with UTF-8

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

---

**The Big Picture - a different approach**

Going back to the origin of the problem, if what you need (if not, sorry for the OT... but it may be useful the same) is to place an ***arrow*** at the end of your HTML element, like a custom *Select Box*, or a *Menù Item*, then the question is simple, and no esotic characters needs to be involved:

1. [Create the desired shape with CSS only](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/);
2. To apply that shapes to pseudo elements, set the content to empty (`content: '';`), and adjust the placement with `absolute: position` relative to the parent element; <kbd>[**Running Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/zKmPW/)</kbd>;
3. To prevent the ["Weird dark border" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956228/weird-dark-border-after-css-arrow-in-firefox) on firefox, always use `RGBA` (CSS3 RGB with Alpha-channel, set to 0 and hence transparent) instead of `transparent`, as described [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956793/1654265);
4. Forget about using sort of *Wingdings Fonts* for graphic in your pages :)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. It only suggests a completely different approach to the assumed goal behind the question asked.

Comment: It absolutely does. Out of the box thinking is generally considered a skill, unless you are in the army, or you are a robot. If the goal is really the one supposed, this answer improves drastically the approach and the knowledge of the problem; it is complementary to the other comments / answers suggesting the solution to the immediate problem, though. I never asked this to be selected as the accepted one, just felt the urge to share it. But you are right, I could have included that in my answer too, for more completeness. I'll do it now.